# Proper factors and subsets of integral domains

Tags: ring-theory, factoring

We want to prove that if $R$ is an integral domain (with identity element $1_R$), then $a$ is a proper factor of $b$ (a proper factor meaning, there exists $c$ in $R$ such that $b = ac$, and $c$ is not a unit in $R$) if and only if $Rb \subsetneq Ra$ is true.

To prove this we have to prove both directions, I know how to prove the forward direction but having problems with the backwards direction.

A weaker condition can be proved by the following argument:

Since $Rb$ is a subset of $Ra$, if take some identity element $1_R$, it is trivial to see that $1_Rb = ka$, for some element $k$ in $R$, hence in this case it's obvious $b$ is a factor of $a$. However this only proves a certain special case of this statement, and the condition is also weaker.

I'm wondering if anyone have an idea how to start proving this fact?

Answer (score 1):

Starting where you left off, the only thing remaining is to show $k$ isn't a unit.

If to the contrary it were a unit, then $bk^{-1}=a$ Implies $a\in bR$, hence $aR\subseteq bR$, and equality, contradicting the assumption the containment is proper.

Thus, you have the property in your second line.