# Integral domain and proper factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, divisibility, ideals

> Let $R$ be an integral domain and $a,b\in R$ where $a\mid b$ but not
> $b\mid a$. I have to show that this implies that $Rb \subsetneq Ra$.

The question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673063/proper-factors-and-subsets-of-integral-domains) one.

He however proved the direction I don't know how. I believe I have to show that (a) $Rb$ is a subset of $Ra$ and (b) that $Ra\neq Rb$. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition $a \mid b$ implies that there is a $d \in R$ such that $da = b$. Therefore, we have $b \in Ra$, which implies $Rb \subseteq Ra$.

To show it is not equal, notice that, if it was, then $a \in Rb \implies a = cb$ for some $c \in R$. But this would imply $b \mid a$, which is false by hypothesis.